# ActiveAdmin: Add association on object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When creating a new object and connecting it with existing (has_many :through) resources I need to:

1. Save the new object first
2. Edit this newly created object again to add connections to the nested resources.

Cumbersome! It seems ActiveAdmin tries to create the association first, *then* the main object. Is it somehow possible to do this object creation + associating nested resources in one go?

---

Is case a more concrete example is needed, here is an example of my data model and ActiveAdmin setup:

```rb
Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations, through: :person_organizations
end

Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, through: :person_organizations
end

PersonOrganization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :organization

  validates :person, presence: true
  validates :organization, presence: true 
end
```

```rb
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :name
  end

  f.inputs 'Organizations' do
    f.has_many :person_organizations, do |connection_f|

      connection_f.input :organization, as: :select,
                                        collection: Organization.select[:id, :name],
                                        member_label: proc { |org| org.name }

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```rb
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations, allow_destroy: true
```

and if you haven't also the

```rb
    has_many :person_organizations
```

in your Person model, and you can place

```rb
    f.input :organizations, :multiple => true
```

in your form. Also make sure you permit the correct params in your activadmin register block. In this case it would be

```rb
    permit_params :name, :organization_ids => []
```

Read carefully:  https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#nested-resources and https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#setting-up-strong-parameters

I like to decorate multiple select inputs with the select2 javascript library. Let me know if something does not work out.